# OpenSSH defaults (sshd_config) on root server

Tags: ssh

So while trying to set up an sftp user I apparently broke the sshd_config.
Since the moment I changed it I can't connect via SSH and FTP anymore: Connection refused.

My server hoster provides a function to boot into a recovery mode which starts into a zsh shell.
But me failing at doing a backup of the original config and not having enough knowledge to rewrite it myself, I got stuck here. I don't even find something like apt-get or aptitude in zsh. I also noticed that every line in the sshd_config is now commented out by a hashtag.

Any ideas how to proceed with this?

Comment: It would help if you presented current, broken setup, so we know what to fix. You can always anyway try to reinstall ssh with its default settings.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simplest to purge and reinstall `openssh-server`. If not, you can extract it from the `postinst` script.

```
sed '1,/EOF/d; /EOF/,$d' /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst > /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```